# Why in the World is the UserName/Login Field Filling with Random String of Numbers and Letters?

Tags: javascript, autologin, sharethis

The username/login field autofills with numbers and letters - I have checked the JavaCode, hunted the web for others experiencing the same problem but found nothing.

http://scottjaxon.com/gotchalegaldev/

sample of generated string (and I'm not trying to generate anything in the login field)
ab722fa-134c68dddcf-7d431b6-82

7639673-135df770710-11a7fb05-70

Is this coming from a conflict with the ShareThis Javascript?
Or is this a serverside error conflicting with AutoLogin.aspx?

any hints, tips or solutions are very much appreciated

SJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

- There's a cookie called `"__unam"` being set by ShareThis.com.
- In the `pageLoad()` function in global.js, you're looking for a cookie called `"un"` and using it to preset the username field.
- Your cookie parsing function (`getCookie()`, also in global.js) is poorly written - it just checks whether the name of the desired cookie is *found within* the name of each cookie in `document.cookie`, rather than *equal to*:

  ```
  if (key.indexOf(idStr.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
  ```

So `getCookie("un")` matches the `__unam` cookie, gets that cookie's value (which happens to be some sort of hash string), and then inserts it into the username field.

Comment: Sweet!~ That rocked it. Thanx for droppin' that bomb of knowledge on me.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely JavaScript from somewhere. Try changing the `id` of the text box to something different and see if that fixes it.